# Symfony2 + FOSRestBundle: Enable/disable REST functionality per controller/action?

Tags: rest, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

A part of my application will be available as an **API**, so **some of my pages** needs to be available in JSON or XML (based on the Accept header 'Content Type').

I've used the **FOSRestBundle** and it works very well, but now **ALL** my pages are available in XML (or JSON) when sending Accept header 'Content Type: application/xml'.

So, I would like to enable/disable this functionality for some of my controllers/actions. I would be ideal to do this using annotations.

Is that possible?

*My config.yml:*

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            rss: false
            xml: true 
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: false
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
        view_response_listener: force
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: acme.decoder.json
            xml: fos_rest.decoder.xml
    format_listener:
        default_priorities: ['html', 'xml', 'json', '*/*']
        fallback_format: html
        prefer_extension: false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the RestBundle's documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/), you won't get an XML output if you don't use a `View` in your controller. So, if you don't use the `@View` annotation, or a `View::create()` in your action, and you return a classic response, you will get a HTML output.

If you want to force the format for some reasons, you can turn the `prefer_extension` to `true` and adjust the routing definition:

```
my_route:
    pattern:  /my-route
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:action, _format: <format> }
```

Where `<format>` is the format you want to force.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `view_response_listener` to `false` (default is `force`). And then add `@View` annotation to each of your controller classes, where you want to use REST.

Example will make it clearer.

A controler without REST:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/comments")
 */
class CommentsControler extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function newAction() { ... }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     */
    public function detailAction($id) { ... }

    ...
}
```

And another controller with REST. Notice that only `@View` annotation for the class is required (unless you want to override response status code).

```php
/**
 * @View
 * @Route("/api/comments")
 */
class RestfulCommentsControler extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function newAction() { ... }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     */
    public function detailAction($id) { ... }

    /**
     * @View(statusCode=204)
     * @Route("/{id}/delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction($id) { ... }

    ...
}
```

- `View` is `FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View`
- `Route` is `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route`

Comment: It works for me. Are you using correct `View` annotation class? Can you provide more information?

Comment: If you `use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;`, your annotations should be `@Rest\View` rather than `@View`